# Connecting to external webservice method from anuglar application

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am a total newbie, so please forgive me if the question seems silly.
I've gotten an url directly to external service POST method which is a part of service bus. My front app is written in angularJS. How do I connect to this method? So far I've been using some mocked data in ASP.NET MVC Controller calling it in angular service:

```
MyService.search = function (parameters) {
    return $http.post('/Home/Search', parameters);
};
```

What is the way to call this external method? Should I build some logic in Controller? Create a webservice calling this external one?
I will be very grateful for some help.

Edit: Error I am getting after simply replacing my mocked URL to the proper one calling search method:

[Exception... ""  nsresult: "0x805e0006 ()"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:7311/scripts/angular.js :: createHttpBackend/< :: line 10704"  data: no]

return logFn.apply(console, args);

Comment: Did you tried to call it with the full url?

Comment: When I simply changed my mocked url (/Home/Search) for the one I got I get the following exception after hitting search button:
[Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:7311/scripts/angular.js :: createHttpBackend/< :: line 10704"  data: no]
 

return logFn.apply(console, args);

Comment: Its better to put the error message inside the question. that way we can read it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a couple of things.

1. Connect to the service using your browser (if this works try it inside your $http.post)
2. Make sure the service has CORS enabled, otherwise it is not possible to connect from a different domain.

Comment: Yes, I corrected small misspeling and now I am getting missing CORS error.
What if I would like to create my own service (calling this external one) to be able to modify data a little bit before passing it to the UI?

Comment: That is possible... But you still need to fix the CORS error, this can only be done serverside. this means that if you are not able to change this you need to ask the creator of the service

Comment: I have already written to service devs about it. Could you please tell me where should I look for information how to create service calling external one? Not sure if it's this day but I do not even know how to ask Google about it.

Comment: If you want to write your own service there are a couple of things you need to think about. the first one is what technique am i going to use (WCF for example) if you have your technique determined you can take a look how to do a service call from your own service to the one you want. and manipulate the data from that service. Instead of calling the external service from your angular application you will call your own service which calls the external service.

Comment: Hi. I just made ApiController which calls all the external methods (and it works! :) ). Is this a good practise? Or should there be a separate layer of service and then controller calling this service?

Comment: That depends... If this is working for you and you think its a good idea to do it like that i should not change it. This is more a discussion about the architecture of your program. If you want you can open a new thread about what is the best architecture of my program. And specift which problems you have...